# "GoogleApiClient is not connect yet" on signout but signin success

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, google-signin

I'm trying to create a project using google signin on android and google drive on a server. 
So first I create the client:

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.main);

        FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn_demarrer).SetOnClickListener(this);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
                .RequestEmail()
                .RequestServerAuthCode("my-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .RequestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"))
                .Build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .EnableAutoManage(this , this)
                .AddApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .AddApi(DriveClass.API,gso)
                .Build();
    }
```

I handle signin button click:

```
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.Id)
        {
            case Resource.Id.btn_demarrer:
                var signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                StartActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
                break;
        }
    }
```

And handle result:

```
    public void HandleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result)
    {
        if (result.IsSuccess)
        {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.SignInAccount;

            string s="";
            try
            {
                System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                var url="http://myserver?code="+System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(account.ServerAuthCode);
                byte[] r = Client.DownloadData(url);
                s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(r, 0, r.Length); 
            }
            catch(System.Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                while(e.InnerException!=null)
                {
                    e=e.InnerException;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }

            if (!s.Equals("auth code received"))
                UpdateUI(false);
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateUI(false);
        }
    }
```

And on the server side everything is ok, I receive a valid code and can use google drive.
But in fact `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected` is never set to `true` even if the signin process seems ok (`result.IsSuccess` is true, and the server auth code is valid). 
And if I try to signout I get the well-known java exception `GoogleApiClient is not connect yet`

What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line `.AddApi(DriveClass.API,gso)` solved the problem, if someone can explain that. I understand that it is not needed as the server will handle the drive api but why it "breaks" the signin process ?